# Passing array of Latitude and Longitude in google map API

Tags: jquery

I am using google map API for dragging marker in particular location only.For that i have to pass latitude and longitude to map to set polygon in map.So i have an array of latitude and longitude of a city.But when i pass that latitude and and longitude to another array then all time latitude becomes 0 after loop execution.Below is my snippet of it.

```
 var lat_lon_arr= [[101.47947471,3.39363238],[101.48004052,3.39358892],[101.48061623,3.39364326],[101.48166269,3.39390932],[101.48329894,3.39441147],[101.48720732,3.39049983],[101.48777824,3.38987883],[101.48814927,3.38936611]];

 var boundary  = [];
lat_lon_arr.forEach(function(item,index,arr) {
        console.log(arr[index][0] + '---' + arr[index][1]);
        boundary.push(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[index][0],arr[index][0]));

});
console.log(JSON.stringify(boundary));
```

The output of the above is as below :

```
[{"lat":90,"lng":101.47947470999998},
{"lat":90,"lng":101.48004051999999},{"lat":90,"lng":101.48061623000001}
,{"lat":90,"lng":101.48166269000001},{"lat":90,"lng":101.48329893999994}
,{"lat":90,"lng":101.48720731999992},{"lat":90,"lng":101.48777824000001}]
```

Comment: should not you push arr[index][1]? I see you're pushing both 0th element to the boundary array

Comment: Ya i have tried the following code but still get latitude 90.                   
                                                                                                  
  boundary.push(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[index][0],arr[index][1]));